# textarea text content not changing - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm basically trying to get the contents in the textarea for comparison purposes, but the .text() or .val() never changes even when I change the content within the textarea box

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#getContents').click(function() {
           console.log($('#txtarea').text());
      });
 });


 <textarea id="txtarea">test</textarea>
 <input type="submit" id="getContents" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/THTsG/

Comment: Try removing test text from textarea. Don't specify default text

Comment: @ProgrammersOcean what's wrong with default text?

Comment: @RUJordan Sorry I was wrong, you need to use .val()

Comment: Your fiddle is working exactly as you would hope for me...Some other issue? `text()` works fine.

Comment: did you remember to update/run your jsfiddle after you changed the text() to val()?

Answer (score 6):

When working with a `textarea`, use `.val()` (I see you said you tried it, but it does work):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/THTsG/1/

jQ:

```
$('#getContents').click(function() {
    console.log($('#txtarea').val());
});
```

Comment: @anothershrubery -- OP's original fiddle wasn't working for me with `.text()` -- Chrome.

Comment: This is a lifesaver! Thank you for this insight.

Answer (score 1):

if use

```
.val();
```

instead of

```
.text();
```

all seems work properly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THTsG/)

Answer (score 0):

I have update your jsFiddle.
It's recommended to use .on to have a dynamic control on your object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getContents').on("click", function() {
        alert($('#txtarea').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks for using jsFiddle.

Use .val, just as tymeJV says. However, note that you don't have to wait until the submit is clicked. You *can* have code sense when the textarea changes. However, it does wait until the user is done changing it and clicks something other than the text area.

Here's what I drafted up for you at jsFidde http://jsfiddle.net/khV4T/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtarea').on('change', function() {
    console.log($('#txtarea').val());
    });
});
```